# open pdf files in acrobat reader from sharepoint online

Tags: document-library, pdf

I want my users to be able to open all pdf files directly with Acrobat reader. They have the desktop client installed on their devices.
I have also changed the settings in the document libraries to open up in desktop clients by default but it doesn't work for Adobe pdf files.
Any suggestions if this is possible or any workarounds available for SharePoint Online?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this stage I have not found a way to open PDF files directly in Adobe Reader, however Microsoft have recently [announced](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2023/02/08/adobe-acrobat-microsoft-edge-pdf/) that the Edge Browser will start using Adobe Acrobat PDF engine soon.

> To meet the needs of organizations with managed devices, the
> transition to the built-in Microsoft Edge PDF reader with the Adobe
> Acrobat PDF engine will occur in phases:
>
> - March 2023: Unmanaged device rollout will begin in March 2023. Managed
>   devices can opt-in using policy via Intune.
> - September 2023: Rollout to
>   organizations will begin no earlier than September 2023. Organizations
>   with managed devices may opt out of this experience via Intune policy.
> - March 31st, 2024: The legacy PDF engine in the Microsoft Edge PDF
>   reader is scheduled to be removed (and opt-out no longer available) on
>   March 31st, 2024.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that users use the "Sync" button in the document library so that they can access the library from Windows Explorer via the OneDrive for Business desktop app. By accessing the library from Windows Explorer, they can open PDFs directly in Adobe Acrobat. They'll need to ensure that Adobe Acrobat is their chosen Windows application for PDFs (which they can do by right clicking on a PDF and using the "Open with" option).

[Sync SharePoint files and folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-and-folders-87a96948-4dd7-43e4-aca1-53f3e18bea9b)